# OneToOne relationship in Spring where foreignkey are used

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-one

how to implement one-to-one bidirectional relationship in hibernate for following tables:

```
create table persons(
                       person_id varchar(20) not null,
                       first_name varchar(20) not null,
                       last_name varchar(20) not null,
                       primary key client_fk (person_id)
);
create table roles(
                     person_id varchar(20) not null,
                     role_name varchar(20) not null,
                     role_description varchar(20) not null,
                     constraint role_person foreign key role_fk (person_id) references person(person_id)
);
```

I want to establish reationship between *PersonEntity* and *RoleEntity*.

I tried many different setups but without success, for instance:

```
@Entity(name = "persons")
@Table(name = "persons")
public class PersonEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    int personId;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    String lastName;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private RoleEntity role;

@Entity(name = "roles")
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    int personId;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private PersonEntity person;
    @Column(name = "role_name")
    String roleName;
```

My objective is to create two *CrudRepositores* (*RolesRepository* and *PersonsRepository*) in order to retrieve all persons with assigned role and all role with assigned person.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

> My objective is to create two CrudRepositores (RolesRepository and
> PersonsRepository) in order to retrieve all persons with assigned role
> and all role with assigned person.

This means that a Role belongs to multiple Persons. That makes the relationship definetly not @OneToOne. Therefore you have not taken the right road.

**If a Person has only 1 role but 1 role belongs to multiple persons then you must use in**

1. PersonEntity Class -> @ManyToOne `RoleEntity role`
2. RoleEntity Class -> @OneToMany `List<PersonEntity> personEntities`

**If a Person has multiple roles and each role belongs to other Persons as well then you need**

1. PersonEntity Class -> @ManyToMany `List<RoleEntity> roleEntities`
2. RoleEntity Class -> @ManyToMany `List<PersonEntity> personEntities`

If your structure has the right logic your crud repositories will work. If not you will face problems. By trying to force @OneToOne to a relationship that is not @OneToOne is like hacking and trying to exploit some functionalities of hibernate to achieve what you want. I don't think that this will work well.